# ICommand и получение ссылки на окно

Tags: c#, wpf

Добрый день, занялся реализацией кастомной команды. Реализовал `ICommand` и все отлично работает, но возникла мысль, а хорошо бы получать данные о месте вызова комнады (например ссылку на окно).

В `RoutedCommand` при вызове команды в качестве источника передается класс к которому мы привязали команду с помощью `CommandBining`'а. 
Хочется сделать такой же вариант, для передачи в качестве одного из аргументов но без использования `CommandBinding`.

Возможно ли это или нет?

Текущий вариант взятый из `RoutedCommand` не подходит :( вот он:

```
private static IInputElement FilterInputElement(IInputElement elem)
    {
        if ((elem != null) && ((elem as DependencyObject) is UIElement))
        {
            return elem;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Используется эта конструкция примерно следующим образом:

```
var parent = FilterInputElement(Keyboard.FocusedElement);
```

Comment: Нормальный способ - это передача окна как параметра из биндинга

Comment: @Monk Согласен, но тут скорее академический интерес.

Comment: Академически - подобная передача нарушает паттерн MVVM...

Comment: В MVVM команде не должно быть нужно окно. VM окна - может быть, но тогда её можно передать другими способами, хоть в конструктор.

Comment: @PavelMayorov т.е. в `RoutedCommand` источник указывается сугубо в технических целях и его не стоит использовать?

Comment: Вам не должно хотеться получить окно или другой визуальный элемент. Смысл команд в том и состоит, чтобы абстрагироваться от визуальной части, и сосредоточиться на самих данных. Если вам нужно окно — скорее всего, ваш код не должен выноситься в команду, это код, работающий с представлением..